# Finding datasets embedded in R GISTools package?

Tags: r, sp, sf

How can I find the embedded datasets in R package GISTools?

I can find examples of datasets (Georgia, Newhaven etc.), but I cannot see exactly which datasets are available.

Comment: I've answered your first question and edited out your second because we like to keep things to one question per posting here. If you want to ask your second question then make a new post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all the data in a package with:

```
> data(package="GISTools")
```